# Qt - load bmp565 into QPixmap

Tags: qt, bmp, qpixmap

I am working on application which needs to load bmp 16bit(5-6-5) images to QPixmap. Is there any way in Qt of doing this directly like for 24bit bmp's?

I tried to convert all images to 24bit version and there were no problems with loading them. Unfortunately I really need to work with 16bit.

I tried also the following code, but without success. However I could load 16bit (1-5-5-5) version of my bmp.

```
QImage img = QImage(300, 300, QImage::Format_RGB16);
img.loadFromData(imgArray);
ui->test->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
```

Comment: Can you give an example of such image? I tested on my own RGB565 just loading using QImage constructor and it works.

Comment: This is one image I am trying to load.
http://expirebox.com/download/e982f3ad20a97a0d968f8109ef5587f6.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work pretty well for me using the QImage constructor:

```
QImage::QImage(const QString & fileName, const char * format = 0)
```

Basically, the use would be:

```
QImage img = QImage("filename.bmp")
```

and the RGB16 format should be picked up by the constructor on its own from the file header.

### EDIT:

The file you posted seems to be using a header type that is not supported by Qt. It is an undocumented header with size 56 called `BITMAPV3INFOHEADER`, which [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) explains as:

> Not officially documented, but this documentation was posted Adobe's
>   forums, by an employee of Adobe with a statement that the standard was
>   at one point in the past included in official MS documentation
>   https://forums.adobe.com/message/3272950#3272950

It seems to be a quite special header type that is not supported by many libraries. However, gimp or ImageMagic can load it and convert it, so I suggest that you converted your files to another BMP file with RGB565 encoding that uses a more standard header. Then, the above code will work for you.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot pass QImage::Format_RGB16 to loadFromData(...) because its not const char * type.

Comment: I tried the default constructor with path to file only, but this did not work for me.

Comment: Thank you... I finally wrote a code where I am reading data from bmp image into QByteArray with offset of 70 (for skipping the header), converted to uchar string and  used QImage(const uchar * data, int width, int height, Format format) to read the image. Now, loading seems to work (although image is reversed). But anyway, your answer is correct and I think I will rather convert the images to appropriate header as you suggested.